# Drupal устарел или нет?

Tags: drupal, php

Чем фигоов друпал?

Устарел ли он?

Посмотрел код, похоже на какое то школьное говнокодство

На работе проекты пишут на друпале заставляют учить

Учить (перспективно?) или искать другую работу и не париться?

Comment: меняй работу, учи нормальные фреймворки типа yii или codeigniter, не трать жизнь зря.

Answer (score 1):

Учить, Друпал не плох но порог вхождения несколько выше чем жумлу или вордпресс.
Все что ты выучишь за плечами не носить. А в будущем может очень помочь.

Answer (score 1):

друпал сейчас перепиливается с применением компонентов Symfony2, вот тут https://github.com/drupal/drupal/tree/8.x можно посмотреть код.

по этому теоретически есть перспектива, что друпал станет когда-нить адекватной цмской, а на счет чего учить - то тут без вариантов - Symfony2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону Yii - все его хвалят и навешивают над Drupal'om - сколько знаю перспективных студий - занимаются разработкой на этом фреймворке... 
Порог вхождения такой же как у друпала - однако стиль работы немного другой..

Вдогонку http://habrahabr.ru/post/131901/ - достаточно полезный обзор как опора моей точке зрения...

Answer (score 0):

Для всего есть свои инструменты. Друпал имеет широкий спектр различных функций. От визитки до магазина. При этом, задача должна быть относительно стандартная. Хотя можно взять и запустить друпал только ради регистрации пользователей и отображения морды, а остальное написать самому, например какой-то сервис. Но в этом случае это может стать заколачиванием гвоздей микроскопом, и я бы предпочел лучше делать на yii2.

А если тебе нужен сайт, для которого есть решение с помощью модулей друпал, либо с небольшим дописыванием, то лучше Drupal не придумаешь. Нужно помнить, что Drupal - это CMF, т.е. в первую очередь контент.

НО! Из всего что есть на рынке по управлению контентом сейчас, друпал - самое универсальное и расширяемое решение.